# (jquery-ui) toggleClass color transitions on items with set CSS colors

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

I am trying to use the jquery-ui toggleClass (with a duration) to add a class with a color to an element which has already had its color set explicitly in CSS.

Unless I tag the color in the class I am toggling *to* as "!important", this color doesn't stick once the transition is completed. If I DO set it as "!important", the color fades in one direction as expected, but doesn't return smoothly in the other.

One solution I had implemented previously as a work-around was to assume a 2-color scenario, and just use jquery's **animate** to manually set the color on the hover event instead of using toggleClass. However, I am now trying to use this in a situation in which the *starting* color of the element is **not known** prior to applying this effect.

Any ideas as to how to achieve a smooth transition in both directions would be greatly appreciated.

See this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BM6NT/

Comment: weird thing.. adding `.fancy,a.fancy` to the css makes the color stick http://jsfiddle.net/BM6NT/5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this will fix it  http://jsfiddle.net/BM6NT/7/

```
a.fancy, div.fancy {
    margin-left:5px;
    color:orange;
}
```

Comment: thanks very much. I will mark as answer asap and upvote whenever I get enough reputation.. =)

Comment: Thanks I appreciate it.  Try using firebug in firefox or the inspect tool in google chrome, it will show you what css is being applied to an element and what is being overruled.

Comment: Those are great tools (I prefer firebug overall), but I was still having trouble figuring this one out. Thanks